# Chakra UI - "Open Modal" button cannot be clicked multiple times

Tags: typescript, next.js, chakra-ui

Chakra UI modal dialog in Next.js is not working properly.
I am trying to implement the following code in pages/index.tsx to display a modal dialog.

```
import type { NextPage } from "next";

import {
  Modal,
  ModalOverlay,
  ModalContent,
  ModalHeader,
  ModalFooter,
  ModalBody,
  ModalCloseButton,
  useDisclosure,
  Button,
} from "@chakra-ui/react";

const Home: NextPage = () => {
  const { isOpen, onOpen, onClose } = useDisclosure();

  return (
    <>
      <Button onClick={onOpen}>Open Modal</Button>

      <Modal isOpen={isOpen} onClose={onClose}>
        <ModalOverlay />
        <ModalContent>
          <ModalHeader>Modal Title</ModalHeader>
          <ModalCloseButton />
          <ModalBody>text</ModalBody>

          <ModalFooter>
            <Button colorScheme="blue" mr={3} onClick={onClose}>
              Close
            </Button>
            <Button variant="ghost">Secondary Action</Button>
          </ModalFooter>
        </ModalContent>
      </Modal>
    </>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

However, once I click the "Open Modal" button, I cannot click it again.
This code was adapted from the [official documentation](https://chakra-ui.com/docs/components/overlay/modal#usage).

Comment: That code works for me on a Next.js app. Do you get any errors in the browser's console?

Comment: @juliomalves I didn't get any errors in the console, but thanks to your reply, it solved itself. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and fixed it by updating `framer-motion` to version 6 (from `4.1.17` to `6.3.10` to be precise):

```bash
npm install framer-motion@6
```

This is [a known issue](https://github.com/chakra-ui/chakra-ui/issues/5321) in Chakra v1 and React 18 which is fixed in v2. I had updated to Chakra v2 but missed the `framer-motion` update.

Comment: Thanks for this, this saved me countless hours

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the npm package and this problem has been resolved.

```
npm install -g npm-check-updates
ncu
ncu -u
npm install
```